# Android "KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException" on simulator restart

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

Without adding or removing fingerprints, which I know invalidates the key, restarting the android simulator does the same. I haven't been able to find any information on this. Are keys invalidated on device restart? That would be really inconvenient.

I don't think it is something in my code, everything works fine while the simulator is on.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the emulator. I tested in a device and it works fine.